# Need help registering Google Cloud Function URL as verified domain to receive push notifications

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-cloud-functions

Am trying to call google calendar's push notification apis. I have written a google cloud function which just returns a response containing request body and headers. I want to use this google cloud function url as the receiving url for the push notification. The [google docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#registering-your-domain) mention steps to verify and register the domains, as part of which it asks me to upload a binary. Not sure how do upload a binary against this cloud function domain. My domain looks like https://asia-northeast1-project-name.cloudfunctions.net

This was my request for registering push notification:
Request:

> POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/watch?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
>   {  "id": "404713b9-d880-437d-b890-83715f01af7c",  "type": "web_hook", 
>   "address":
>   "https://asia-northeast1-huddle-quick-solutions.cloudfunctions.net/suratCalendarNotifications" }

Response:

> {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
>       "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://asia-northeast1-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/path"    }   ],   "code": 401,   "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback
>   channel:
>   https://asia-northeast1-project-name.net/path" 
>   } }

Comment: You need to use an access token.  Web hook is private data api key will only work for accessing public data.

Comment: Hmm, does it mean webhook http endpoints can’t be registered as webhook receiving urls ? Hmm, guess I’ll need to try it over a more conventional app engine

Comment: @adityaparikh can you give a little more information? Did you ever get this sorted?